# What counts as a "short-lived event" for the purposes of document.execCommand()?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

When trying to trigger `document.execCommand('copy')`, I sometimes find it useful to wait a short amount of time for a background process to finish a computation (for example) before actually copying a result to the clipboard.

I see from some [online docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard) that this command is limited to "short-lived events" triggered by users, for security reasons (which I completely support!).

However - what actually counts as a "short-lived event," and how variable is the behavior across browsers? I can't seem to find definitive answers.

Comment: `wait a short amount of time` how are you doing this?

Comment: Using setTimeout, typically